# ColorAnimation help?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I'm trying to do a coloranimation in WPF so that a newly exposed UI element appears with a red border that fades to white over time.  Here is the code I have:

```
        SolidColorBrush toFade = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

    private void showElement(SuperTB.SuperTextB toShow)
    {
        toShow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        toShow.BorderBrush = toFade;

        ColorAnimation fadeToWhite = new ColorAnimation();
        fadeToWhite.To = Colors.White;
        fadeToWhite.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(fadeToWhite, "toFade");
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fadeToWhite, new PropertyPath(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty));
        Storyboard fade = new Storyboard();
        fade.Children.Add(fadeToWhite);
        fade.Begin(this);
    }
```

and in my MainWindow constructor I have

```
this.RegisterName("toFade", toFade);
```

When the method is called, the desired element appears but there is no color animation.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I will tell you straight up, I have only done animation in code once and it was horrid.  I then handjammed an animation in XAML in VS2008 and it was horrid.  Then I got a [**copy of Expression Blend**](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/try-it/) and animated in the designer...

So much easier, and it looked better too since I could more accurately control the animation.  Do yourself a favor and get Blend, it is totally worth it.  It takes a little bit of getting used to, but it will be a huge time saver in the long run.

Comment: I wonder about that, while Blend may be the best of the bunch it's still generating code i myself don't like all much, i prefer to handcode because then i know where everything is and how it is structured. Further if you do it for some time animating in C# or XAML becomes quite natural as well.

Comment: @H.B. Nothing wrong with generating code for educational purposes. Looking at how it's done and then using that information to enhance. :)

Comment: Indeed.  Once you get into the animations in Blend, you may see that there are some things that you really will only do in a designer.  Path animations, easing functions, offset animations, etc.  I can only imagine the work going into animating an item on an offset that is itself moving.

Answer (score 0):

You are complicating things too much i would say, you only have one animation so there is no need for a storyboard, just call [`BeginAnimation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.animatable.beginanimation.aspx) on the Brush and that's it. e.g.

```
Action<TextBox> animMethod = (TextBox x) =>
    {
        var brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        x.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        x.BorderBrush = brush;
        brush.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, new ColorAnimation(Colors.White, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
    };
animMethod(tbtest);
```

Also, if you have to use a storyboard in code behind do *not* use the [`TargetName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.targetname.aspx) property but simply the [`Target`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.target.aspx) property as you have a proper reference rather than just the name.